# Change panel heights in a Resource Function Grid of Plots

Tags: plotting, resourcefunction

I'm trying to produce a vertical grid of plots sharing the same 'x' axis. I do it this way:

```
Plot1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"];
Plot2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"];

JointPlot = {{Plot1}, {Plot2}}

ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][JointPlot, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Grid of plots with both panels with the same height. I aim to have the upper panel bigger than the lower one.]

I'm aiming to achieve the top panel being bigger than the bottom panel, i.e. to increase the top panel height and reduce the bottom panel height. An example can be the following figure:

[image: Example of a Grid of Plots with panels with unequal heights.]

I tried 'AspectRatio', but that affects to both panels in the figure, even though I only apply it to one.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Plot1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"];
Plot2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"];

ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{{Plot1}, {Plot2}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, 
 ItemSize -> {Automatic, {1 -> 2}}]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!